# Add FK Value to existing table entry

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got some issues with my database on Android.

There are two tables. The first one `TABLE_LISTELEMENT` handles all the data that one element needs to have.

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_LE =
        "create table " + TABLE_LISTELEMENT + "(" +
                COL_LEID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                COL_PRODUCT + " text, " +
                COL_LABEL + " text, " +
                COL_SERIAL + " text, " +
                COL_MAC + " text, " +
                COL_DAAID + " text, " +
                COL_BILL + " text, " +
                COL_FK_RID + " REFERENCES room(rid)" + ")";
```

I've added the `COL_FK_RID` foreign key to reference my second table (`TABLE_ROOMS`)

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_R =
        "create table " + TABLE_ROOM + "(" +
                COL_RID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                COL_RNAME + " text" + ")";
```

Now I've got these two tables but I am not sure how to add the FK to my first table.

First I create Elements of `TABLE_LISTELEMENTS` and show them in a `ListView` . Now I want to take all of the `ListView` entries and add a room.
Therefore I select all of the entries of `TABLE_ELEMENTS`with :

```
public boolean insertRoomNr(String room){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor dbCursor;

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("roomname", room);
    db.insert(TABLE_ROOM, null, contentValues);
    String RaumId ="";
    RaumId = db.rawQuery("SELECT rid FROM room WHERE "+ COL_RNAME + " = ?",new String[]{"null"}).toString();

    ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("fkrid", RaumId);
    db.update(TABLE_LISTELEMENT, contentValues2 , " WHERE fkrid IS null", null);
    return true;
}
```

But how can I now add a room to my `TABLE_ROOMS` and relate him to all the entries which I have selected. (I've got a `EditText` and a `Button` which I use to enter the room number).

I hope that you understand my problem.

Comment: To add a row to a table, use [insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)). To change a column value in one or more rows, use [update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

Comment: I changed my `insertRoomNr` method. But it is still not working. Im not sure how `update` is working. 
1. I take the room String and put it in my `TABLE_ROOM`. Now I have the room and the room ID in my table
2. now I want to check the room ID which I wrote in the TABLE to add it in my `TABLE_LISTEELEMENT` 
But how can I perform this? My way to save the ID in a String seems to be not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it. Now I use 2 methods. The first to insert the new roomName and the second to update the ID.

```
public boolean insertRoomNr(String room){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("roomname", room);
    db.insert(TABLE_ROOM, null, contentValues);
    Log.d("raumname", room);

    return true;
}

public boolean insertRoomId(String roomFromEditText){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("UPDATE listelement SET fkrid = (SELECT rid FROM room WHERE roomname = '" + roomFromEditText + "')");

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something like:

```
public boolean setData(String data1, String data2) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("data_example1", data1);
    contentValues.put("data_example2", data2);

    db.insert(TABLE_EXAMPLE, null, contentValues);

    return true;
}
```